# How do you add an option to CMake called by python

Tags: python, cmake

I am trying to add a commandline option to a CMake command but unfortunately, the CMake command is called in a python file.

In the setup.py file, there is a class called CMakeExtensions:

```
class CMakeExtension(Extension):
    def __init__(self, name, sourcedir=''):
        Extension.__init__(self, name, sources=[])
        self.sourcedir = os.path.abspath(sourcedir)
```

I am trying to add the following option:

```
cmake -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2k -DOPENSSL_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2k/li
```

The original setup.py can be found here:

https://github.com/citp/BlockSci/blob/master/setup.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is where they're adding the [extensions](https://github.com/citp/BlockSci/blob/master/setup.py#L34).

Simply change

```
    cmake_args = ['-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=' + extdir,
                  '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=' + sys.executable]
```

to

```
    cmake_args = ['-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=' + extdir,
                  '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=' + sys.executable,
                  '-DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=' + yourPathHere,
                  '-DOPENSSL_LIBRARIES=' + yourPathHere ]
```

**Though I don't recommend it, and I'm sure there's a better way.** But I'm not familiar with this library, and this will solve your issue.

Comment: Since the underlying build here just uses [`FindOpenSSL.cmake`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/module/FindOpenSSL.html), setting the `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` environment variable will also work and won't require touching the Python scripts.